# Visual Studio 2013 debugger, skip system calls

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am debugging in VS 2013 and I want the debugger to just look at my code. I marked the `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> "Enable Just My Code"`, but it still enters, what I guess are, the system calls as well.

How can I make the debugger only consider my code when I debug?

Comment: Please provide examples. "System call" isn't really a well defined term in this context, at least not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a quite an easy one: instead of stepping into (F11) while debugging, I should have used "step over" (F10).